# is it possible to apply a custom class to bootstrap.datepicker buttons

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new with the bootstrap. Currently I am using bootstrap Datepicker `(ui.bootstrap.datepicker)`

In `(ui.bootstrap.datepicker)` buttons from which we navigate months have classes named `.pull-left` and `.pull-right`.

Problem is that I already have those classes in my application. Is it at all possible to rename default bootstrap class or apply custom classes to the bootstrap buttons.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to rename them in your application?

Comment: @bnjmn ohhh no, it'll be one hell of a job, i'll have make changes in atlest 60 files

Comment: then write rules that are more specific based on other classes within the datepicker so that specificity doesn't collide with your app rules. Not much in those 2 classes other than float

Answer (score 0):

You can find the template code in **ui-bootstrap.tpls**. Copy & paste the modules template code:

```
angular.module("template/datepicker/datepicker.html", []).run(["$templateCache",
    function($templateCache) {
        $templateCache.put("template/datepicker/datepicker.html",
            "<table>\n" +
            "  <thead>\n" +
            "    <tr class=\"text-center\">\n" +
            "      <th><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn pull-left\" ng-click=\"move(-1)\"><i class=\"fa fa-chevron-circle-left\"></i></button></th>\n" +
            "      <th colspan=\"{{rows[0].length - 2 + showWeekNumbers}}\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-block\" ng-click=\"toggleMode()\"><strong>{{title}}</strong></button></th>\n" +
            "      <th><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn pull-right\" ng-click=\"move(1)\"><i class=\"fa fa-chevron-circle-right\"></i></button></th>\n" +
            "    </tr>\n" +
            "    <tr class=\"text-center\" ng-show=\"labels.length > 0\">\n" +
            "      <th ng-show=\"showWeekNumbers\">#</th>\n" +
            "      <th ng-repeat=\"label in labels\">{{label}}</th>\n" +
            "    </tr>\n" +
            "  </thead>\n" +
            "  <tbody>\n" +
            "    <tr ng-repeat=\"row in rows\">\n" +
            "      <td ng-show=\"showWeekNumbers\" class=\"text-center\"><em>{{ getWeekNumber(row) }}</em></td>\n" +
            "      <td ng-repeat=\"dt in row\" class=\"text-center\">\n" +
            "        <button type=\"button\" style=\"width:100%;\" class=\"btn\" ng-class=\"{'btn-info': dt.selected}\" ng-click=\"select(dt.date)\" ng-disabled=\"dt.disabled\"><span ng-class=\"{muted: dt.secondary}\">{{dt.label}}</span></button>\n" +
            "      </td>\n" +
            "    </tr>\n" +
            "  </tbody>\n" +
            "</table>\n" +
            "");
    }
]);
```

I would create a new file e.g. Templates.js and put all overridden code there.